# What's the best tool to allow non-developers to create a ponycorn adventure game?

Tags: language-agnostic

This is the ponycorn game: http://www.untoldentertainment.com/games/sissy/
A couple of my non-programmer friends who are teachers are interested in building games with a similar look and feel with their kids. 
What would be a good (the best) tool to get started with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independently of the particular game in question, there are some projects aiming to bring programming closer to non-programmers. The all differ in the level of abstraction though. Some of the most interesting ones :

- [**Scratch**](http://scratch.mit.edu/) visual, lego-like, great for kids, developed by the MIT
- [**Lego Mindstorms**](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) provides visual programming, but I'm afraid, this is not suitable for programming ponys as it concentrates on the mindstorms robotics project.
- [**processing**](http://processing.org/) - a former MIT project. Cross-platform (windows, linux, mac, android) scripting environment, is a rather thin layer over a java framework. very versatile, providing even OpenGL rendering, but your friends will have to write code still - simpler than with most other frameworks but still